# When using APIRouter: Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "app.main"

Tags: python, fastapi

So the app work when I do not include the router.

```
├── app
│   ├── presentation
│   │   ├── user_controller.py
│   ├── main.py
```

main.py:

```
app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(user_controller.router)
```

user_controller.py:

```
router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/users",
    tags=["users"],
    responses={404: {"description": "Not found"}},
)

client = MongoClient(os.environ['MONGODB_CONNSTRING'])
db = client['fullkron']
users = db['users']


@router.get("/")
async def get_users():
    return users.find()
```

I start the app with docker:

```
#
FROM python:3.9

#
WORKDIR /code

#
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

#
RUN pip install  --no-cache --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt

#
COPY ./app /code/app

#
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0" , "--reload" , "--port", "8000"]
```

It doesn't start when I include the APIRouter but does when not.

Comment: share your dockefile

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by `It doesn't start when I include the APIRouter but does when not.`?

Comment: So when I comment out the app.include_router(user_controller) it works, otherwise i get Error loading ASGI app Could not import module "app.main".

Comment: what's the full error/stacktrace?

Comment: also make sure you have `__init__.py` in every subdirectory